# Regex for gsub to match line until and through newline \n character

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Trying to build a regex for R gsub to match a string through a newline character to be deleted.

Sample string:

```
text <- "categories: crime, punishment, france\nTags: valjean, javert,les mis\nAt the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

Ideal outcome will be to gsub replace the first two blocks of text so that what's left is just the text afterwards.

At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more.

getting rid of the categories and tags.

Here's the pattern I'm working with:

```
^categor*.\n{1}
```

It should match the start of the line, everything after the word fragment, until it reaches the first newline, but instead it's only matching the fragment. What am I doing wrong?

And, is there a better way than two gsubs to knock this out?

Comment: The expected output is what's after the last newline? Can you post what you want as output of that example string?

Comment: Is this it: `sub(".*\\n([^\n]*$)", "\\1", text)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** There is some question of what is being asked here so this first option removes the first two lines:

```
sub("^categor([^\n]*\n){2}", "", text)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

If the `categor` part doesn't matter so does this:

```
tail(strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]], -2)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

**2)** If what is wanted is to remove any line of the form `...:....\n` where the characters prior to the colon on each line must be word characters:

```
gsub("\\w+:[^\n]+\n", "", text)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

or

```
gsub("\\w+:.+?\n", "", text)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

or

```
grep("^\\w+:", unlist(strsplit(text, "\n")), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

**3)** or if we want to remove lines having just certain tags:

```
gsub("(categories|Tags):.+?\n", "", text)
## [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

**4)** Using `read.dcf` might also be of interest if you also want to capture the tags.

```
s <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
ix <- grep("^\\w+:", s, invert = TRUE)
s[ix] <- paste("Content", s[ix], sep = ": ")
out <- read.dcf(textConnection(s))
```

giving this 3 column matrix:

```
> out
     categories                  Tags                     
[1,] "crime, punishment, france" "valjean, javert,les mis"
     Content                                                         
[1,] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

Comment: Instead of `tail(., -2)` wouldn't `tail(., 1)` be more intuitive?

Comment: only if just the last line is wanted. I think all but the first two are wanted which is the same for this example but might not be.

Comment: Thank you! Solution 2 was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (newline is matched with `\\n`:

```
gsub("^categor.*\\n",  "", text)
# [1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following regex:

```
sub("^categor.*\\n([^\n]*$)", "\\1", text)
#[1] "At the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
```

Answer (score 0):

No need using `[^\n]` because you may use a mere `.` to match anything but a line break char. Mind that you need to use `(?n)` modifier with TRE (default regex engine with `(g)sub`/`(g)regexpr`), and with `perl=TRUE`, it is the default `.` behavior:

```
text <- "categories: crime, punishment, france\nTags: valjean, javert,les mis\nAt the end of the day, the criminal Valjean escaped once more."
sub("(?n)^categor(?:.*\n){2}", "", text)
sub("^categor(?:.*\n){2}", "", text, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, the first two lines are removed if the string starts with `categor`.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Yhc5p9).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `categor` - a literal substring
- `(?:.*\n){2}` - exactly 2 consecutive occurrences (`{2}`) of any char but line break chars (`.`) zero or more times (`*`) followed with an LF char.